# GeoNode layer permissions GUI

Tags: geonode

I have some GeoNode instances (versions 2.4 & 2.6) running on Ubuntu virtual machines and am trying to restrict a layer to only registered users. According to the [docs](http://geonode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/security.html) one should be able to edit permissions of a layer on the GeoNode GUI:

> You can now choose whether you want your layer to be viewed and
>   downloaded by
>
> - anyone
> - **any registered user**
> - a certain user (or group)

But when I go to my.geonode/layers/my_layer -> "Change Layer Permissions" (logged in as admin = superuser), all I see is this:
[image]

The problem is: I don't want to set permissions on specific users or groups but want to let ALL registered users (there are a lot, so I want to avoid adding each single user or creating a group containing all users) view this layer, i.e. deny access to anonymous users. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As far as i know, current stable 2.6.3 version does not have the option "any registered user", and even the docs you linked state so. There´s another option of restricting certain URLs to only registered users through local_settings (set LOCKDOWN_GEONODE=True and add public URLs to AUTH_EXEMPT_URLS), but that will make all your layers unseen by non registered users.

Comment: Too sad this is not yet implemented. I tried to set permissions programmatically with layer.set_permissions({'users': {'AnonymousUser': []}}, as suggested here: https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/tests/integration.py but this won't work either. So the only way to achieve this is to add each user on its own or to create a group that contains all users...?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a way to do it in geonode, but If you want you can give permission to download data to **any registered user** by changing html files.

If user not logged in to the system, to hide **Download Layer** button in layer view page, just add this if statement `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` in layer_detail.html before `<li>` tag.

```
sudo nano /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/layers/templates/layers/layer_detail.html
```

and go to line no 141 and add `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

before `<li class="list-group-item">`
and then close if statement `{% endif %}` in line no 149 after the `</li>`

after changed the layer_detail.html file,

line no 139 to 153

```
<ul class="list-group">
  {% if resource.storeType != "remoteStore" %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
    {% if links %}
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download-layer">{% trans "Download Layer" %}</button>
    {% else %}
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" id="request-download">{% trans "Request Download" %}</button>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

then restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

now if user not logged in user can't see the download layer button.

if you want, you can do this to map details page also
(map details page path : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/maps/templates/maps/map_detail.html`)

Comment: I belive Franka wants a (single or fiew) layer(s) to be seen or downloaded only by registered users. This procedure will keep unregistered users from downloading ANY layer in GeoNode.